# Specular lighting does not appear

Tags: c++, directx11, hlsl, visual-studio, specular

I'm struggling to add specular lighting on-top of diffuse lighting and not entirely sure where I'm going wrong.  I've followed the instructions given in our lecture but it just doesn't seem to be appearing on-top at all.

[image: picture of textured sphere with diffuse lighting]

light_vs.hlsl

```
// Light vertex shader
// Standard issue vertex shader, apply matrices, pass info to pixel shader
cbuffer MatrixBuffer : register(b0)
{
    matrix worldMatrix;
    matrix viewMatrix;
    matrix projectionMatrix;
};

cbuffer CameraBuffer : register(b1)
{
    float3 cameraPosition;
    float padding;
};

struct InputType
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
};

struct OutputType
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float3 worldPosition : TEXCOORD1;
    float3 viewVector : TEXCOORD2;
};

OutputType main(InputType input)
{
    OutputType output;

    // Calculate the position of the vertex in the world
    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.position, worldMatrix);
    output.viewVector = cameraPosition.xyz - worldPosition.xyz;
    output.viewVector = normalize(output.viewVector);
    
    // Calculate the position of the vertex against the world, view, and projection matrices.
    output.position = mul(input.position, worldMatrix);
    output.position = mul(output.position, viewMatrix);
    output.position = mul(output.position, projectionMatrix);

    output.worldPosition = mul(input.position, worldMatrix).xyz;
    
    // Store the texture coordinates for the pixel shader.
    output.tex = input.tex;
    
    // Calculate the normal vector against the world matrix only and normalise.
    output.normal = mul(input.normal, (float3x3) worldMatrix);
    output.normal = normalize(output.normal);

    return output;
}
```

light_ps.hlsl

```
// Light pixel shader
// Calculate diffuse lighting for a single directional light (also texturing)

Texture2D texture0 : register(t0);
SamplerState sampler0 : register(s0);

cbuffer LightBuffer : register(b0)
{
    float4 ambient;
    float4 diffuse;
    float3 position;
    float padding;
    float specularPower;
    float4 specular;
};

struct InputType
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float3 worldPosition : TEXCOORD1;
    float3 viewVector : TEXCOORD2;
};

// Calculate lighting intensity based on direction and normal. Combine with light colour.
float4 calculateLighting(float3 lightDirection, float3 normal, float4 ldiffuse)
{
    float intensity = saturate(dot(normal, lightDirection));
    float4 colour = saturate(ldiffuse * intensity);
    return colour;
}

float4 calcSpecular(float3 lightDirection, float3 normal, float3 viewVector, float4 specularColour, float specularPower)
{
    // blinn-phong specular calculation
    float3 halfway = normalize(lightDirection + viewVector);
    float specularIntensity = pow(max(dot(normal, halfway), 0.0), specularPower);
    return saturate(specularColour * specularIntensity);

}

float4 main(InputType input) : SV_TARGET
{
    // Sample the texture. Calculate light intensity and colour, return light*texture for final pixel colour.
    float4 textureColour = texture0.Sample(sampler0, input.tex);
    float3 lightVector = normalize(position - input.worldPosition);
    float4 lightColour = ambient + calculateLighting(lightVector, input.normal, diffuse);
    
    float4 specularColour = float4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    float specularPower = 512.0f;
    float4 specular = calcSpecular(lightVector, input.normal, input.viewVector, specularColour, specularPower);
    
    return (lightColour + specular) * textureColour;
}
```

Comment: what are your specular values?